# Reusing array; using part of array as parameter

Tags: jqplot

I have very long array of arrays.

```
arr[97] =[['2001-03-12',73.3333],['2001-03-13',73.12],['2001-03-14',69.99],['2001-03-15',70.97],['2001-03-16',67.46] ... ];
```

I'm using jqplot to draw a chart with these values. But I wish to have charts with data restrictions.

Now I'm creating new subarray every time the date restriction was changed.
But it is very unefficnet, takes time and memory.
Can I use only part of already existing array and give it as an agrument for jqplot-chart?

Comment: how about having a hash function which returns indices of array by taking date range as input and modifying jqplot-chart js to work on your array with the help of passed indices.